# How to Stream the audio file between two iPhones using multi peer connectivity framework?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, streaming, multipeer-connectivity

I have been searching for this answer in stackoverflow and i have referred [Multi-peer connectivity tutrial](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/streaming-audio-to-multiple-listeners-via-ios-multipeer-connectivity) as well as [GitHub Code For TDAudioStreamer](https://github.com/tonyd256/TDAudioStreamer) nothing seems to be working. This github code i tried to run but it shows the image and song name but the sons are not getting played back in streams.

Any help or tutorial or code would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The [TDAudioStreamer](https://github.com/tonyd256/TDAudioStreamer)  framework is working fine you need to connect the device into the same network over wifi or bluetooth, and make sure that you select the .mp3 file and make sure you dont have the silent mode on.

Hope this helps

Comment: can we support the mic audio for streaming?